# Find the taylor series for $\cos x$ and indicate why it converges to $\cos x$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Find the taylor series for $\cos x$ and indicate why it converges to $\cos x$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$.

I've posted my own proof, I hope it is correct :)

Answer (score 3):

If $f(x)=\cos x$ for $x\in \Bbb R$, then

$$f^{(n)}(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
-\sin x &n=1,5,9,...\\ 
-\cos x &n=2,6,10,...\\ 
\sin x &n=3,7,11,...\\ 
\cos x &n=0,4,8,12,... 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

thus 
$$f^{(n)}(0)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
-1 &n=2,6,10,...\\ 
1 &n=0,4,8,12 \\ 
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Hence the Taylor series for $\cos x$ is

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}x^{2k}$$
The derivatives of $f$ are all bounded by $1$, so

$$\cos x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}x^{2k}$$

for all $x\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: All seems good. Can you spell out how $|f^{(n)}|\le 1$ implies that the Taylor series converges to the function?

Comment: @Berci Let $x \in \Bbb R$, then $|R_n(x)|=|\frac{f^{(n)}(y)}{n!}x^n|\leq \frac{|x|^n}{n!}$ for all $n$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x|^n}{n!}=0$, we conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty} R_n(x)=0$.

Comment: Yes. Great. Perfect.